# Usage of a non blocking assignment in Verilog

Tags: verilog

Is the usage of non blocking assignment in the below example (in `state == 2'b01`) valid? It simulates fine but how will that synthesize?

```
module test(input wire [7:0]a, input wire clk, output reg [11:0] b);
reg [1:0] state;
reg [7:0] mem [0:4095]
integer i;
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(state == 2'b00) begin
        //some logic
    end
    else if(state == 2'b01)
        state <= 2'10;
        for(i = addr; i < addr + 64; i = i+1)
            if(a == mem[i]) begin
                state <= 2'b00;
                //some logic
            end
        end
    end
    else begin
        //some logic
    end
end
endmodule
```

Comment: Just make sure you're setting state in every possible path.

Comment: @samuelnj Why? If it's not explicitly set in one path, it stays the same in the next clock cycle as in the current clock cycle. No need for `state <= state`.

Comment: True, it isn't explicitly necessary but I think it's good practice in Verilog since doing otherwise in a non-sequential block can introduce unintended latches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Non-blocking assignment (`<=`) is the appropriate way to model sequential logic.
2. The code you've shown means: If the state is currently `01`, then if any of the 64 memory locations starting from `addr` are equal to `a`, then the next state will be `00`, otherwise it will be `10`.

   If that is what you want, the code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your non-blocking usage is OK, but you are reading 64 memory values **at the same time**.

See my answer [Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/377657/is-this-matrix-vector-multiplication-function-in-vhdl-parallelized/377667#377667) about HDL and loops and what happens with loops when you synthesize.

---

Unless you have a memory with 64 ports you can't do that. Your tool might build it but it will probably use 32768 registers, not a memory. If the tool is very, very clever it might split up your design in 64 memories each 64 entries deep.

If this is the functionality you need I would split up the memory myself in 64 blocks and read all 64 at the same time.

By the way : if your building a cache, that is not the way to do it. You normally would have a TAG memory.

Comment: Yeah. That is exactly what i want my code/hardware to do(compare 64 values at the same time and decide on which state to go accordingly).